# Regex to match [] but not \[\]

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

How can I get all matches for `[.*]`, but not if the brackets are backslash-escaped like `\[.*\]`?

I can use the JavaScript function `new RegExp("\\[.*\\]", "g")` to get all `[.*]`. How can I exclude all `\[.*\]` (escaped brackets)?

Input looks like this:

```
div\[data-custom-attribute='References'\][matchme]
```

In this case, the regex should match `[matchme]`.

Comment: Why not use regex literals to create the regular expression to void having to double escape the backslashes?  `/\[.*\]/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rubular.com/r/16q3jSPHN0

`[^\\](?:\]?(\[(.+?)\]))` should work for most cases.

**Edit:**

Seems like this will not match `\[test\][test]`, as Rory pointed out. For that, I can't really think of a *good* solution without using multiple regexps, but if you want just *one* then try this: http://rubular.com/r/QBqFAbqW9E

`(?:[^\\](?:\]?(\[(.+?)\]))|((?:\]?(\[(.+?)\])))\\)`

Match groups will be populated in the first 3 if it a block with escaped brackets occurs *after* a regular block, and the last 3 if the opposite occurs.

```
Match 1
1.   
2.   
3.  [test]
4.  [test]
5.  test
Match 2
1.  [test]
2.  test
3.   
4.   
5.
```

Comment: JavaScript [does not support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so this is the best you can do. But if JavaScript did, it would be better to replace `[^\\]` with `(?<!\\)`, so that you could match strings beginning with `[`, like `[test]\[test\]` ([before](http://rubular.com/r/Zu2TuNCVm7), [after](http://rubular.com/r/fop7evuIA5)).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane ah you're right. I think it would be wise to use two expressions, one for each case, at least as far as JS is concerned. Alternatively, I updated my comment with a single expression that seems to catch both cases, but it does displace grouped results depending on the position of the escaped blocks. Can't think of a better solution.

Comment: Why don't your test strings contain any backslashes? A single backslash in a string escapes the next character (if anything), so your single backslashes aren't actually part of the string, meaning you're not testing data accurately. In a real example, your first regex doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/A6XBH/1/

Comment: Note that in `[foo][bar][baz]` it will only match the `bar`. And yeah, in JS you can't do much better than to use `(?:^|[^\\])` instead of `[^\\]`.

Comment: @dav i will use 2 regex queries. how can i get 2 matches instead of 1 for \[data-custom-attribute='References'\][matchme] ?

Comment: @Abc In hindsight, I think it would be better if you used a single regular expression to find all escaped blocks, remove them (e.g. replace with `""`), and then use another regular expression to find all the regular blocks. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/A6XBH/2/

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is knowing whether you're looking at an escaped bracket (`\[`) or a bracket that follows an escaped backslash (`\\[`).  That's easy enough if you're only looking for one match:

```
/^[^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*(\[[^\]\[]+\])/
```

The first part gobbles up any characters other than backslashes or square brackets.  If it sees a backslash, it grabs that and the next character, whatever it is.  It repeats that process as many times as it can, and when it can't do that any more, the next thing has to be the bracketed value (or "tag") you're looking for.  It's captured in group #1.

Getting the rest of the tags is trickier.  To stay in sync with the data, you want each subsequent match to start exactly where the previous match left off.  Many regex flavors support the `\G` anchor for just that purpose, but it doesn't help us.  JavaScript is in the process of adopting the `/y` flag, which does essentially the same thing, but you can't count on that yet.

Here's a workaround that should work for case:

```
/(?:^|\[[^\]\[]+\])[^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*(?=(\[[^\]\[]+\]))/g
```

The core regex is the same, but the capturing group is now inside a lookahead.  The first time around, it starts matching at the beginning of the string like before, but it stops just short of the first tag.  The lookahead confirms that the tag is *present*, but doesn't consume it.  The next match starts by matching the tag again, this time consuming it.  Meanwhile, the tag is also captured in group #1, so you can access it in the usual way.

```
var regex = /(?:^|\[[^\]\[]+\])[^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*(?=(\[[^\]\[]+\]))/g;
var match = regex.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // tag is in match[1]
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-catchable group like `[^\\]` :

```
[^\\]\[.*[^\\]\]
```

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is *non-capturing* group, but what you've got there is actually a negated character class, and it doesn't solve the problem.  For one thing, your regex won't match `[test]` at the beginning of the string because it needs to consume a character before the opening `[`.  You may be thinking about negative lookbehind, but JavaScript doesn't support those.